# How do I find out what is planned for the next version?

Tags: development

Where can we find out what the expected changes for the next version of Ubuntu are?

Comment: Normally "Ubuntu+1" questions are not appropriate here, but I double-checked [this Meta question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate) and this seems okay according to the highest-ranked answer.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 I beg to differ, `Questions about features coming up in the release. This should be encouraged, as it's useful for users who might not know how to find information on the upcoming features (especially around the time of UDS) - however we need to be diligant as to not get swamped with hand wavy pseudoquestions: Will Unity be more customizable? is an example of a question that is unanswerable.` - I'd say this is a hand wavy "pseudoquestion", since all we know for sure is stability, and configuration. Anything other than that would be pure speculation.

Comment: should the question be closed then? I only asked since when I get the same question asked by different users I tend to put it here. Since this is a question that already has some straight forward answers that mention what to expect. For example sites like http://www.techdrivein.com/2011/11/6-key-changes-in-next-ubuntu-1204_12.html and http://www.webupd8.org/2011/11/expected-changes-in-ubuntu-1204-precise.html mention this in a more easy to understand manner. I will change the way the question is asked, still if it does not qualify as a question here I will close/remove it.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado We decided in chat that this question can stay if it's generalized to how people can find out about planned changes for development versions of Ubuntu in general.

Comment: I would concur that this is a good question—though it perhaps needs some help to come across as such. Is there an official (aka *.ubuntu.com) place to see what the planned changes are?

Comment: @zpletan If there is such a place, it'd make for a great answer below. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to keep track of news of new features is to read one of many well-known blogs or news sites that are Ubuntu-specific during each release's development cycle. Examples include [OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/) and [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/).

If you don't mind wading through mounds of technical stuff, there are [blueprints for Ubuntu at Launchpad](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu) that could offer some clues as to what will come in the next release.

Lastly, there is the [Ubuntu Contributors Channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/ubuntudevelopers) on YouTube, which keeps a large collection of video recordings from the Ubuntu Developer Summits, as well as interviews with some of the developers.

Comment: I have rewritten this answer to match the updated question. *(Note: if anybody still wants to see the original answer I wrote for 12.04 specifically, just click [here](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/79591/2). ;) )*

Comment: Excellent updated question.